# Reporting Services buttons show up one under the other instead of side-by-side

Tags: sql-server, ssrs

This seems a browser problem to me.  When I render a reporting services report in IE11, the "Export", "Refresh" and "Export to Data Feed" buttons show up under each other taking up a lot of extra screen space.  Does anybody know what could be causing this?

I am running Reporting Services 2012:

[image]

My IE version:

[image: IE Version]

and here is how the buttons appear:

[image: RS Buttons]

Comment: Looks like you need to install up to at least [SP1 CU8](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/810527/sql-server-reporting-services-is-not-compatible-with-internet-explorer-11) or hack around with [some files](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21141223/73226)

Comment: Thank you, Martin!  Installing SQL2012 SP1 CU8 update did the trick for me!  Note that hacking around with files as suggested [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/810527/sql-server-reporting-services-is-not-compatible-with-internet-explorer-11) did not help

Answer (score 1):

I found this self-answered question on Stack Overflow - maybe it will help you.

[SQL Server Report Manager report showing export, refresh, data feed buttons on separate lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23143473/sql-server-report-manager-report-showing-export-refresh-data-feed-buttons-on-s)

Answer (score 0):

Just adding this comment, so it shows up as "answered", but all the credit goes to Martin Smith:

Thank you, Martin! Installing SQL2012 SP1 CU8 update did the trick for me! Note that hacking around with files as suggested [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/810527/sql-server-reporting-services-is-not-compatible-with-internet-explorer-11) did not help